# Coloring single cells in tabular

Tags: tables, color

I've tried for a while to color single cells in a `tabular` enviroment.

So far, I've tried the following

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{color, colortbl}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{| l | l  |} 

\hline
\cellcolor[RGB]{200,200,50} A Cell! & Another cell\\
\hline
A third cell! & Does this ever stop!?\\
\hline

\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

But when showing in Adobe reader, at different zoom levels, the borders of the cell disapears strangely.

I suspect that the color within the cell overwrites some of the border linings?

Is there a way to make the color only fill strictly the inside of a cell?

Comment: It's an issue with Adobe Reader...

Comment: It also looks the same in TeXMakers preview, and in chrome?
Is there a way I can then make it 'campatible' with these flawed viewers?

Comment: I use SumatraPDF and the issue is not visible.

Comment: Noproblem in SumatraPDF. By the way, it's pointless to load coor,if you load xcolor.

Comment: And it's pointless to load `colortbl` separately in your case: the instruction `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}`, which is in your preamble, loads the `colortbl` package in a way to preserve full interoperability with the `xcolor` package.

Comment: Allright, yet, even if i put only `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}`, there still seems to be issues with the colors overwriting cell borders. Is there simply no way around this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a viewer issue.